# Oozie Coordinator configuration for multiple File Dependancy

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Is it possible to configure the Oozie coordinator that can trigger a workflow to process each group of files under these conditions:

Group is defined by me as simply a collection of files under a parent directory.
Every xx mins a Groups of Files are loaded into its corresponding  HDFS directory.
Each group of files represents tables from a specific database.
Each Group of files are contain in their own Parent HDFS Folder eg Database1, Database2.

File names are all different names inside each parent / group  folder name.
What I would like oozie to do (thats if its possible) is:
Scan that all files in that specific parent directory exists, each file name will be different and are typcially named after the tables that those delimited files represent.

If all files exist (From a template defined in Oozie) then i exexute the workflow.

how configurable is oozie, my guess is that it may not be that flexible to handle this specific request, but I would love to know from you guys your thoughts.

My hands are tied in terms of changing the folder / file-structure into HDFS.
I need to know the right questions to ask the guy responsible for generating the incoming files.

Any insight / experience would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From your query it seems you don't have directory path ending in some date pattern which could have been used to trigger coordinator.

You can use combination of switch feature and  shell/java action to achieve this -

1> Have your coordinator frequency to start workflow very low - say 5 min.

2> As you mentioned you have table template I am assuming you already know table names which are expected to be in particular directory. Write simple shell or java action to recursively check for these directory and return true if all tables exists.

3> use switch feature of workflow to proceed further if all tables exists or exit :-

```
<decision name = "table_exists">
    <switch>
        <case to = "proceed_further">${wf:actionData('check_directory')['exists'] eq 'true'}
        </case>
     <default to = "end" />
  </switch>
</decision>
```

Note that above check_directory is action which can be written in any language in proper way to return value. Please check the ooziedoc or update me in case you need help to write this action.